# How to convert layout to drawable for use in splash screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, splash-screen

## Background information

When a user enters my Android application. They are first taken to `LoginActivity`. `LoginActivity` takes some time to load as it is also responsible for performing background sqlite migrations as well as other housekeeping tasks (this takes 500-1000ms).

Unfortunately, the user sees a blank screen during this entire time. As `setContentView` has not executed yet.

I am trying to remediate this problem by following the guides

- https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52
- https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

They tell me I need to create a `background_splash.xml` in drawables and point to it using a custom style with `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>`

Unfortunately I noticed that I am not able to control `padding` `margin` `width` `height`, `gravity` of my logo in drawables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

        <!-- cant control android:margin=... (my min API is 21) -->
        <!-- cant control android:width=...  (my min API is 21) -->
        <!-- cant control android:height=... (my min API is 21) -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

### My problem

How to properly achieve same behavior (or at least similar) as my current `activity_login.xml` file and convert that into a drawable?

### My code

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/material_red_500">

    <!--***********************************************************
    * Layout section: The login logo
    ************************************************************-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            android:src="@drawable/image_symbol_lock"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--***********************************************************
    * Layout section: The login button (facebook)
    ************************************************************-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/button_facebook"

        android:paddingTop="28dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="28dp"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_500"

        android:text="LOG IN"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create a layout_splash with your own design and in the Splash style only set a background color. So first you will see the background color and not the blank and next see the layout. You could do this with the login activity.